# SSIS Package triggered by BAT file failing with: Could not create DTS.Application because of error 0x80040154

Tags: batch-file, ssis

I have created an SSIS package in visual studio 2019 that is used to transfer data from excel files to a database table.
I am using a BAT script to trigger the ssis package. As the creator of the package, I can successfully execute the package, but other users on the shared folder are unable to execute this package.

They get the following error:

```
Started:  10:03:02 AM
Could not create DTS.Application because of error 0x80040154
Started:  10:03:02 AM
Finished: 10:03:02 AM
Elapsed:  0 seconds
SSIS Package execution failed. Error code: 1
```

I have already converted my SSIS to use 32 bit only, and made sure my DTExec is also 32 bit.

I am expecting the users of the shared folder to be able to trigger SSIS to push data to the database

The definition of the batch script is

```
@echo off 
set "SSISPackagePath=\\FDB\d\Dispatch\TEST\Dispatch.dtsx" 
set "DTExecPath=\\FDB\Binn\DTExec.exe" 
"%DTExecPath%" /F "%SSISPackagePath%" 

if %errorlevel% equ 0 ( echo SSIS Package executed successfully. timeout /t 15 /nobreak >nul exit ) 
else ( echo email xxxx at xxx@abc-group.com. Share the error screenshot. echo SSIS Package execution failed. Error code: %errorlevel%)
```

Comment: You are transferring from Excel to Database table.  What is the connection string in the SSIS using?  If it is using the user running it do they have access to the database and the table?  Do they have proper access to the Excel file and path?

Comment: What is the definition of the .bat file?

Answer (score 0):

While I wait for the definition of the bat file, I am going to assume the file looks something like

```
dtexec.exe /file Path\to\package.dtsx
```

and the batch file is in some central location, like a file share  \server\share\ImportData.bat

If these assumptions are correct, then your batch file will never work because the users will not have access to `dtexec.exe` and your organization certainly will not want to license SQL Server for each user's desktop as that would become a very expensive proposition. It works on your machine as you have the tooling installed to develop and run the packages but only you.

Installing that to the users desktop might seem like a quick way to get around the error but it will not address the licensing issue because you'd be running a production workload using a developer license and in the event of an audit, that's a willful level of violation versus accidental and that gets expensive.

### How can I let users run an SSIS package ad hoc?

It depends! At the most simple level, the package will always pick up a file with a static name from a static location, then I'd

- create a SQL Agent job to run the package
- Create a mechanism for the users to run the job (reuse your bat file)

Perhaps something like

```
sqlcmd -S myserver -d msdb -Q "EXECUTE dbo.sp_start_job 'Run_ye_package'"
```

That assumes the users have permissions to log into the database and start a job (operator role). They probably don't have that, so now you get to solve the problem of "how will I let my users talk to the database" Maybe you grant them access. Maybe you create a neutered SQL Account that can only run a single Agent Job and embed the clear text credentials in the bat file.

Without knowing how your organization works, their security posture, and the requirements around how this import should perform, it's hard to say specifically what you should do.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. The files and the package both sit in a central location. 
This is the definition of the BAT file:
@echo off
set "SSISPackagePath=\\FDB\d\Dispatch\TEST\Dispatch.dtsx"
set "DTExecPath=\\FDB\Binn\DTExec.exe"

"%DTExecPath%" /F "%SSISPackagePath%"

if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
    echo SSIS Package executed successfully.
    timeout /t 15 /nobreak >nul
    exit
) else (
 echo email xxxx at xxx@abc-group.com. Share the error screenshot.
    echo SSIS Package execution failed. Error code: %errorlevel%
)

pause

I will try out the sql job method. Thanks